# Controller gets initiated twice

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-routing, angularjs-controller

I have a simple controller (logincontroller) which gets initiated twice when loading login.html, however I do not know why that happens.

**MyApp.js:**

```
angular.module('PVM', [
    'Authentication',
    'Modal',
    'ngRoute'
])
.config([
    '$routeProvider', function($routeProvider) {
        $routeProvider
            .when('/Login', {
                controller: 'LoginController',
                templateUrl: 'Login.html'
            })
            .when('/Home', {
                controller: 'ModalController',
                templateUrl: 'Home.html'
            })
            .otherwise({
                redirectTo: '/Login'
            });
    }
]);
```

**LoginController.js:**

```
angular.module("Authentication")
.controller("LoginController",
[
    "$scope", "$rootScope", "$location", "AuthenticationService",
    function($scope, $rootScope, $location, AuthenticationService) {
        AuthenticationService.ClearCredentials();

        $scope.login = function() {

            var foo = "bar"; //Breakpoint hits here twice when loading login.html
        };
    }
    ]);
```

**index.html:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="PVM">
<head>
<title>My Ang</title>
<link href="Content/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="Content/bootstrap-theme.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="Content/MyCss.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1">

</head>
<body>
<div>
<div ng-view></div>
</div>


<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-2.0.3.min.js"></script>
<script src="Scripts/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.5.0-beta.2/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.5.0-beta.2/angular-route.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.5.0-beta.2/angular-animate.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.5.0-beta.2/angular-cookies.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-ui-bootstrap/0.14.3/ui-bootstrap-tpls.min.js"></script>


<script src="Scripts/Services/ModalService.js"></script>
<script src="Scripts/Services/AuthenticationService.js"></script>
<script src="Scripts/Controller/LoginController.js"></script>
<script src="Scripts/Controller/ModalController.js"></script>
<script src="Scripts/MyApp.js"></script>


</body>
</html>
```

**Login.html:**

```
<div class="container centeredDiv" ng-controller="LoginController">
    <p>Login page</p>
</div>
```

Comment: It's because you instantiate the controller twice: once in your `$routeProvider` and once again in your view via `ng-controller`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because your controller gets executed at 2 places.

1. From login.html - ng-controller

   ```
   <div class="container centeredDiv" ng-controller="LoginController">
       <p>Login page</p>
   </div>
   ```
2. From controller associated with route - /Login

   ```
   .when('/Login', {
      controller: 'LoginController',
      templateUrl: 'Login.html'
   })
   ```

How to fix? You should remove the `ng-controller` attribute from login.html

Comment: And hows the proper way to do it?

Comment: You should remove ng-controller from login.html. See my updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

You do not need the ng-controller in your template login.html because it is in your route. Simply remove it and that should do the trick.